# Facebook SDK - iOS - Fail to share URL (Error 102)

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to integrate a simple URL Share on my App, following the dedicated Facebook tutorial ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/))

On my app, I simply click on a button, which displays a dialog where I can type in a comment.
This part works find. Yet, when I click on "Post", I get the following error :

> Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=0x14dd1a10 {error_message=Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.  Please check the application name configured by the dialog., app_id=000000, error_code=102}

(In this message, I just replaced  with zeroes the app_id I got from the Facebook developer page.)

On the Facebook app settings, I set the following as such :

- "Display name" : the same name as the app name
- "Bundle ID" with the string return by `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];`
- The app is "live" (not in sandbox)
- "Deep Linking" and "Connect to FB" : both activated

When I save my settings on the FB dev page, I get a warning saying that I did not set an AppStore identifier (which is not yet available since I am developing the app).

Can you please tell me the little thing that I did not do correctly ?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

I'll be happy to provide you with more info if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried removing "deep linking"? You do not need to select that.  Also the app can be sandboxed and you can still test your iPhone app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the issue was that I set the FacebookDisplayName param with a wrong value.

Comment: I found a solution for special utf8 chars in facebook display name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050613/facebookdisplayname-on-ios-with-german-umlauts-solved

Comment: after spending two days on this issue, mine was due to providing incomplete link for the "image". Using NSURL.path instead of NSURL absoluteString, returns code 102 by facebook SDK

Comment: My error was using fileUrlWithPath instead just string

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This usually comes from you setting the FacebookDisplayName in your .plist, but what you set there didn't match the name of your app in your app settings on Facebook.

The value you give in FacebookDisplayName must match what you have set on Facebook.

Comment: Okay, that was the issue ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Also, I used a test Facebook account, which was not verified. With a verified account, it worked fine !

Comment: Answer is very helpful to me at Android integration.

Comment: @Ming Li This is definitely the correct answer. Make sure there are no special characters or punctuation in your display name. I removed a full stop & a hypen, and everything worked. Essentially name your app FB Display Name like a variable...

Answer (score 13):

Check Following if error 102 comes

1. **FacebookDisplayName** is set properly and correct in plist URL Scheme
2. **fbxxxxxxxxxxx** is added in the plist
3. **FacebookAppID** is set correctly in plist file
4. in Status & Review section Make sure you have "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" make as YES (By default it is set as No)

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, I missed 4rd case, enabled this and it started to work, thanks @mihir mehta

Comment: I also needed to enable the app as in 4). Thanks!

Comment: Note that answer #4 is configured on the Facebook Developers web site.  The current name of the section is "App Review"  and the current text of the question is "Make <app name> public?"  It is still set to No by default and needs to be set to Yes.

Answer (score 5):

For me none of this solutions worked. It turned out I just had to delete facebookDisplayName record from info.plist. Stranged but it worked

Comment: solved the issue for me as well, still i have problems accepting this workaround

Answer (score 1):

There is also a problem with diacritic signs, you can not use it in FacebookDisplayName... for example č, ž, š etc. If you write all without diacritics, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @user3170877. it can't be used like Japan letter and Korean. i recommend only english to use.

Answer (score 1):

Login to Facebook Developer account and check Status is live or in Development. If it is in Development then change it to live. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers fixed this problem for you, one last thing to check is the Bundle ID in your Facebook App settings.
I had this problem for my iOS app that was using a different bundle identifier depending on the build configuration I used.
You can specify several Bundle IDs in your Facebook App settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your Facebook app status is "development and unavailable to the public" will caused same result.

You may want to change it to public under "App Review" on the Facebook app menu. Or you need to login Facebook as role "Administrators", "Developers" or "Testers"