# The "POST" button in the Facebook Share Dialog is disabled

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

My iPhone app has a simple feature to share an item on Facebook but I am having trouble getting it to work. As a matter of the fact, it worked for a while but for some reason the "POST" button in the Facebook ShareDialog is disabled/grayed out, so the only choice is to "Cancel" the action. What's frustrating is that this used to work, but I don't know when it stopped working.

```
NSString *fbEventObjectUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/event/%@", eventId];
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:fbEventObjectUrl forKey:@"event"];    
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                      actionType:@"og:likes"
                             previewPropertyName:@"event"
                                         handler:handler];
```

A bit more details:

- The app allows the user to share an "event". It is not the built-in Facebook Event object, but a custom object defined in Facebook->OpenGraph->Object Types
- I didn't define a custom `Action Types` or `Stories`, simply want to use the built-in `og:likes` action.
- The app is already in App store and the Facebook Application is defined to be available for public.
- The OpenGraph objects are "self-hosted," that my backend web server will render the object using the URL shown as `fbEventObjectUrl` in the following code. I have verified that this URL is working fine using the Facebook Object Debugger and Object Browser.

I have searched the SO archieve and the only related question is this: [ios facebook sdk v3.11 share dialog post button disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155706/ios-facebook-sdk-v3-11-share-dialog-post-button-disabled). I have verified other basic things like setting up Xcode info.plist etc. Please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer? What's the problem here?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I'm having the same problem. Have also confirmed everything is set right in App Settings and info.plist.