# FBSDKShareButton is disabled even after the user is logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi i am using Parse and facebook sdk to built an app, so i initially use the parse default implementation to log the user in through facebook, using the PFFacebookUtils class. However when i want to share/ post something on the user's facebook profile the FBSDKShareButton is disabled (greyed out).

I have tried giving publish permissions, but that didn't solve the problem, this (http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-share-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/) is the tutorial i tried to used in order to share on Facebook. However such a simple implementation, yet i can't figure out why the share button is disabled. I am sure that the user is logged in.

According to this post  [ios facebook sdk v3.11 share dialog post button disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155706/ios-facebook-sdk-v3-11-share-dialog-post-button-disabled), i have added the website and the app domain for which i want the person to go to however this didn't work. Now i have no idea what else i can do, so please help me with this issue, thanks

Comment: have you managed to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Is it disabled for both link and video or only for the video?

Answer (score 0):

Using `http://` or `https://` in front of `contentURL` fixes the problem.