# Not able to post on wall using [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams] method

Tags: ios, facebook-share, fbwebdialogs

I am working on an existing project in which Facebook SDK 3.23.2 is used. I am trying to share data on FB wall by using the `FBDialogs` `presentShareDialogWithParams` method. Share dialog is opening but while posting data error status is coming & I am not able to post on wall..

Following is my code:

```
FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/ios"];
params.picture = [NSURL
                  URLWithString:@"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png"];
params.name = @"Facebook SDK for iOS";
params.caption = @"Build great social apps and get more installs.";

if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params])
{

    NSLog(@"in app");

    FBAppCall *call=  [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                           if(error) {
                               [ALToastView toastInView:self.view withText:@"error "];
                               // If there's an error show the relevant message

                           } else {
                               // Check if cancel info is returned and log the event
                               if (results[@"completionGesture"] &&
                                   [results[@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {


                                   [ALToastView toastInView:self.view withText:@"Inviting Via Facebook Cancelled"];
                                   NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                               } else {

                                   [ALToastView toastInView:self.view withText:@"Inviting Via Facebook success"];
                                   // If the post went through show a success message
                               }
                           }
                       }];
```

The method is always going to `if(error)` loop & showing status as error. While the same method is working when I am trying to use it by creating a simple new project but it is not working in my app...
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have `error`, please show it. Log it.

Comment: what do you mean by log it?

Comment: What's the error message? You show it in a toast, but it could help us to identify your issue.

Comment: how to check error message?

Comment: If (error){NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);}

Comment: failed to authenticate the application

Comment: why it is giving this error? @Larme

Comment: Is that the FULL error message? If not, you can paste your error message, and check in FaceBook SDK WebSite, or StackOverFlow, Google, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK - iOS - Fail to share URL (Error 102)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541510/facebook-sdk-ios-fail-to-share-url-error-102)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete my facebook display name in `.plist file`.